# Question on android bluetooth requirements

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth

I'm new to android and I just want to know, in order to have bluetooth mouses & Bluetooth keyboards support in my app, do I need the following permissions below at the bottom or is it not necessary? (Or anything else I'm missing).

There is **nothing** mentioned about these two devices in these Bluetooth articles:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth
https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth

I'm not manipulating the controls or anything special, I just want make the app sure is user friendly to the new android computers on the market and tablets that support this feature. I do not care the about headsets, speakers, game controllers, etc.

I **don't** have a Bluetooth mouse or Bluetooth keyboard yet so I can't test it myself and find out.

**Manifest Permissions**

android.permission.BLUETOOTH"

android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"

android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in order to have bluetooth mouses & Bluetooth keyboards support in my app, do I need the following permissions below at the bottom or is it not necessary?

Those permissions are for working with Bluetooth APIs directly (e.g., `BluetoothAdapter`).

Normal Bluetooth keyboard and mouse support is handled by the OS, not by apps. So, if all you want is for the user to be able to type into `EditText` widgets using a keyboard, click on things with a mouse, and things like that, you will not need the Bluetooth APIs and you will not need these permissions.

> I don't have a Bluetooth mouse or Bluetooth keyboard yet so I can't test it myself and find out.

In general, whether the keyboard or mouse is Bluetooth, USB, or is part of the base hardware (Chromebooks, etc.) does not matter. From your app's standpoint, they are all the same.

However, if you want to ensure support for keyboards and mice, you will want to test with keyboards and mice.